# C# Windows Application Form to Html Form

Tags: c#, html, css, winforms, forms

I'm working on a project where I need to convert a C# windows application form to an HTML form programmatically.

I'm having problems with sizing the HTML text boxes appropriately.  I set the width and height to the exact same width and height (in pixels) used on the winforms equivalent but it ends up being bigger than the winforms equivalent.

The other controls (label, groupbox ...) appear OK. Clues anyone?

Comment: you need to take into account the border and padding of the html textbox.  Try adding the css style `box-sizing:border-box` and it should make your box be the size you state (dependant on which browser you use)

Comment: Thanks so much, Pete! Worked great! Can you please post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS trick for Box Sizing would come in rescue for your case:

```
textarea { 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```

More detials you can find here: http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/